# GDB Permissions

Tags: permissions, gdb

I'm attempting to run gdb on an executable file within Ubuntu.  However, when I attempt to `run` within gdb, I get the following error.

```
/vagrant/unit_test: cannot execute: Permission denied
During startup program exited with code 126.
```

I've ensured that the file ./unit_test has the proper execute permissions.  I've also tried running gdb with sudo in front of it, `sudo gdb ./unit_test`.
It might be important to know that I'm using a Vagrantfile to boot up a virtual environment.  Has anyone run into this problem before?

Comment: What's the full path for that file? Is it `/vagrant/unit_test` (notice the first slash, which refers to the root of the filesystem)? What are the permissions for the directory `/vagrant`? Can you show us the permissions (e.g. `ls -l /vagrant/unit_test`)?

Comment: Do you see any errors if, within gdb, you type  `shell ldd /vagrant/unit_test`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that virtual file systems may not be friendly to certain executables (e.g. Qt-built ones) when used with gdb.

In my case, the problem was VirtualBox Shared Folders.  When an executable was in the shared folder for the Windows Host, the Linux Guest gave the "cannot execute: permission denied" under GDB (even though the file could be executed normally).  But when I moved the executable into the Linux Guest's extfs filesystem, it worked.

What's strange is that a simple stdio-based "Hello, World" built from the command line can be debugged fine, while a Qt-built app cannot.  For the sake of argument, here's a dump of what ldd shows for the hello world without Qt:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc8bd07000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fda83d71000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fda83f7d000)
```

And here's what it shows for the Qt mandelbrot sample:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd48441000)
libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /home/hostilefork/Qt/5.13.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f09fa7b4000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /home/hostilefork/Qt/5.13.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f09f9f68000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/hostilefork/Qt/5.13.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f09f97b9000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f09f9613000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f09f9486000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f09f946c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f09f9280000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f09f925f000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f09f91cb000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f09f8fae000)
libicui18n.so.56 => /home/hostilefork/Qt/5.13.1/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.56 (0x00007f09f8b15000)
libicuuc.so.56 => /home/hostilefork/Qt/5.13.1/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.56 (0x00007f09f875d000)
libicudata.so.56 => /home/hostilefork/Qt/5.13.1/gcc_64/lib/libicudata.so.56 (0x00007f09f6d78000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f09f6d72000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f09f6d6d000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f09f6c50000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f09fb034000)
libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f09f6c1c000)
libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f09f6b5d000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f09f6ae9000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f09f69af000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f09f6986000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f09f6782000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f09f657a000)
libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f09f6363000)
```

Presumably it's something about that which makes a difference.

Comment: Yep, I was attempting to debug an application with QT and the shared folder was exactly the problem.  Very strange

Comment: Thank you so much! VirtualBox shared folders were the problem, who would have thought.

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter this error while using vagrant, try to add `mount_options: ["dmode=0770", "fmode=0770"]` to `config.vm.synced_folder` method call inside your Vagrantfile, e.g.:

```rb
config.vm.synced_folder "C:\\Projects", "/projects", mount_options: ["dmode=0770", "fmode=0770"]
```